# angularjs with firebase auth share service

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-service, firebase-security

Halo all,

I want to use angularjs with firebase simple login (facebook). But I have no idea how to 
create the auth share service.

What I want to do is

- create a authentication service
- use this auth service to check if user loggedin in every controllers
- controllers will do the `$location` if user loggedin/not-login

I also new to angularjs but I don't know which services should I use in this situation.
`service` or `factory`?

How can I put the below code in angular service then tell each controller if user logged in or not?

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com");
var auth = new FirebaseAuthClient(firebaseRef, function(error, user) {
   if (user) {
      console.log(user);
   } else if (error) {
      console.log(error);
   } else {
      console.log('user not login');
   }
});
```

Here is what i'm guessing, return `user` value from `authService` so in controllers  if `authService.user` exists then redirect to loggedin page otherwise show login dialog with a
login button to call the following code

```
authService.login('facebook');
```

Let me know if I can do like this, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I'm using so far...

I haven't implemented the redirecting yet but the rest works.

```
p4pApp.factory('firebaseAuth', function($rootScope) {
var auth = {},
    FBref = new Firebase(p4pApp.FIREBASEPATH);

auth.broadcastAuthEvent = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('authEvent');
};

auth.client = new FirebaseAuthClient(FBref, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
    } else if (user) {
        auth.user = user;
        auth.broadcastAuthEvent();
    } else {
        auth.user = null;
        auth.broadcastAuthEvent();
    }
});

auth.login = function() {
    this.client.login('facebook');
};

auth.logout = function() {
    this.client.logout();
};

return auth;
});
```

The AuthCtrl is common to all/most of my pages.

```
var AuthCtrl = function($scope, firebaseAuth) {
$scope.login = function() {
    firebaseAuth.login();
};

$scope.logout = function() {
    firebaseAuth.logout();
};

$scope.isLoggedIn = function() {
    return !!$scope.user;   
};

// src: Alex Vanston (https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma)
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
        }
    } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
    }
};

$scope.$on('authEvent', function() {
    $scope.safeApply(function() {
        $scope.user = firebaseAuth.user;
    });
});
};
```

Comment: Wow, you made my day. I was thinking how to return value and the auth object. Now I got it, separate them.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Regarding factory vs. service, there was a good blog post explaining how to approach the choice that I recommend reading: http://iffycan.blogspot.com/2013/05/angular-service-or-factory.html

In terms of doing authentication, your general approach of assigning signed in state to a variable in a service seems alright. We're thinking about doing a deeper integration with Angular for authentication, but for now this seems like a reasonable approach.